# Getting custom replace to work similar to how PHP PDO works

Tags: php, string, replace

I just want to know how to replace a certain index character with an array constantly like how PDO works in PHP? Here is my code;

The the code

```
    private $string;

    public function __construct($string = null) {
        if ($string !== null) {
            $this->string = $string;
        } else {
            $this->string = '';
        }
    }

    public function getString() {
        return $this->string;
    }

    public function replaceWith($index, $array = array()) {
        $lastArrayPoint = 0;
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < sizeof($this->string)) {
            if (substr($this->string, $i, $i + 1) == $index) {
                $newString[$i] = $array[$lastArrayPoint];
                $i = $i . sizeof($array[$lastArrayPoint]);
                $lastArrayPoint++;
            } else {
                $newString[$i] = $this->string[$i];
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

and the executing code

```
    $string = new CustomString("if ? == true then do ?");
    $string->replaceWith('?', array("mango", "print MANGO"));
    echo '<li><pre>' . $string->getString() . '</pre></li>';
```

Thank you for the help I hope I will recieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys but they did not work the way I wanted it to work. I have found a way to get it too work. Here is the code

```
public function replaceWith($index, $array = array()) {
    $arrayPoint = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $newString = "";
    while ($i < strlen($this->string)) {
        if (substr($this->string, $i, 1) === $index) {
            $newString .= $array[$arrayPoint];
            $arrayPoint++;
        } else {
            $newString .= substr($this->string, $i, 1);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $this->string = $newString;
    return $this;
}
```

if anyone has a better way then you can tell me but for now this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "if %s == true then do %s. Escaping %% is out of the box.";
$string = vsprintf($string, array("mango", "print MANGO"));
echo "<li><pre>$string</pre></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` has an optional `count` parameter, so you can make it replace one occurrance at a time. You can just loop through the array, and replace the next question mark for element N.

```
$string = "if %s == true then do %s";
$params = array("mango", "print MANGO");
foreach ($params as $param)
  $string = str_replace('?', $param, $string, 1);
```